# Building Git on Sparc Solaris 9

Tags: git, gcc, gnu-make, solaris

I am trying to build git from source in Solaris 9 Sparc. I am using the opensource tool chain (gcc and make). I am doing :

```
make prefix=/usr/local all doc info
```

I am getting an error in make :

```
/bin/sh: git: not found
Makefile:2765: *** unterminated variable reference.  Stop.
```

The packages I hav instaled for building are :

```
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    4230656 Sep  2 14:41 atk-1.18.0-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    8043520 Sep  2 14:44 cairo-1.4.10-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    4482048 Sep 26 15:00 curl-7.23.1-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    7905280 Sep  4 07:58 cvs-1.12.13-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    2384384 Sep  3 11:04 dbus-1.0.2-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    122967552 Sep  2 13:51 emacs-23.3-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff     903168 Sep  3 11:19 expat-2.0.1-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    7535104 Sep  3 11:06 fontconfig-2.8.0-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    4377600 Sep  3 11:13 freetype-2.4.2-sol9-sparc-local
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dlsa     staff    152377856 Sep  1 07:44 gcc-3.4.6-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    232949760 Sep 26 14:38 git-sources.tar
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    44610560 Sep  3 10:49 glib-2.25.13-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    93400064 Sep  2 14:32 gtk+-2.12.0-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    1273344 Sep  3 10:55 jpeg-7-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    1039360 Sep  3 11:18 libcroco-0.6.1-sol9-sparc-local
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dlsa     staff    6132736 Sep  1 07:44 libgcc-3.4.6-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    3074560 Sep  3 11:16 libgsf-1.14.7-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    2579968 Sep  2 12:49 libiconv-1.13.1-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff     882176 Sep  2 14:00 libintl-3.4.0-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    1184768 Sep  3 10:58 libpng-1.2.8-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    1329664 Sep  3 11:02 librsvg-2.22.3-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    1347584 Sep  3 11:00 libungif-4.1.4-sol9-sparc-local
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dlsa     staff    2967552 Sep  1 07:44 make-3.82-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    8839168 Sep  2 14:44 pango-1.18.2-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff    1172480 Sep  2 14:52 pygobject-2.14.0-sol9-sparc-local
-rw-r--r--   1 dlsa     staff     139776 Sep  3 11:10 xrender-0.8.3-sol9-sparc-local
```

Seems to me my tool chain is old. What can I do to be able to build this ? Use the Solaris 9 cc compiler and make ?

Comment: Well, what is happening in the Makefile around line 2765?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Solaris but back then GNU make was installed as `gmake`, so you have to run `gmake` rather than `make`. Not sure if this is still the case, but it's worth checking.

Comment: TRACK_CFLAGS = $(CC):$(subst ','\'',$(ALL_CFLAGS)):$(USE_GETTEXT_SCHEME)


    GIT-CFLAGS: FORCE
            @FLAGS='$(TRACK_CFLAGS)'; \   # here
                if test x"$$FLAGS" != x"`cat GIT-CFLAGS 2>/dev/null`" ; then \
                    echo >&2 "    * new build flags"; \
                    echo "$$FLAGS" >GIT-CFLAGS; \
                fi

Comment: So I have managed to get over that error by specifying NO_CURL in the make command. It compiled a lot of files fine (I also had to take the config.mak.in create a copy named config.mak and set gcc as the c compiler). Now I hit another problem : when compiling regex.o it requires a header (stdint.h) which is from C99 standard. Solaris 9 gcc is before that, I think. Is there any way to get around this ?

Comment: The headers come from the OS.  Solaris 10 is the first Solaris version with C99 support.  Solaris 9 is nearly 20 years old - can't you use a newer OS version?

Comment: Found out that Solaris9 has an equivalent header, just with another filename, created a symlink and it passed. With some other issues I encountered, I was able to build git without Curl and iconv. But now I am having some trouble running it because of the executable file format that was generated. I generated it with GNU ld, but when running the executable it uses the OS ld, so I am handling that now.

Comment: Tried replacing the gcc ld executable in /usr/local/bin with a symlink to the solaris one in /usr/bin, but it didn't work. I still get the error : ````Bad elf flags value : 768````. In fact I noticed that this is related to ssh not being able to load libcrypt : ````ld.so.1 : /usr/local/bin/ssh fatal : /usr/local/lib/ssl/libcrypto.1.0.0.so````

Comment: OK, might be that the openssl package I have from sunfreeware is for a more recent arch. I am going to try and compile openssl and go with that

Answer (score 1):

needed packages other than gnu make and gcc :
I installed these from the sunfreeware set of packages.

```
binutils
openssl     I had to build openssl from source because my arch is different
libcurl
libiconv
tcl
tk
```

on file gc.c insert the following :

```
#define SCNuMAX "lu"
```

make a makefile configuration file :

#### git Makefile configuration, included in main Makefile

```
@configure_input@

CC = /usr/local/bin/gcc
CFLAGS = 
CPPFLAGS = 
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
AR = /usr/local/bin/ar
TAR = /usr/bin/tar
DIFF = /usr/bin/diff
PACKAGE_TARNAME = @PACKAGE_TARNAME@
#INSTALL = @INSTALL@        # needs install-sh or install.sh in sources

prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = /usr/local/libexec
bindir = /usr/local/bin
gitexecdir = /usr/local/libexec/git-core
datarootdir = /usr/local/datadir
template_dir = /usr/local/datadir/git-core/templates
sysconfdir =/usr/local/sysconfig 
docdir = /usr/local/doc

mandir = /usr/local/man
htmldir = /usr/local/html
```

I had problems with libcurl so I included in the make command line : NO_CURL=1
I had problems with libiconv so I included in the make command line : NO_ICONV=1